# HTML table borders and spacing showing even when style sets them to collapsed

Tags: html, css

I've created a table using HTML as follows:

```
<table class="test">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">    
                        <div class="test2">
                            <img src="1.jpg" width="100%">
                        </div>                  
                    </td>
                    <td width="33%">
                        <div class="test2">
                            <img src="1.jpg" width="204%">
                        </div>                  
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="50%">    
                        <div class="test2">
                            <img src="1.jpg" width="100%">
                        </div>              
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <div class="test2">
                            <img src="1.jpg" width="100%">
                        </div>                  
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

I then used the following Style to try and remove the spacing and borders:

```
.test
    {
        margin: auto;
        width:1000px;
        height:583px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        padding: 0; 
        position: relative;
    }

    .test2
    {                   
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;       
    }
```

The problem is that it doesn't seem to work as I still get spacing between the cells as can be seen from the image shown here:[image: html table]

Comment: Could you please pinpoint the exact line which, in your opinion, removes the [borders](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#border-shorthand-properties)?

Comment: border-collapse: collapse; - Shouldn't  this remove the border?
 padding: 0;  - Shouldn't this remove the cell spacing?

Comment: [Not at all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse). All it does is collapse borders of adjacent cells into one border. It unifies borders, making sure they do not get doubled. It doesn't remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. By default, browsers add borders to tables. To remove it, you need to override it:

```css
table, table * {border: none;}
```

2. You shouldn't be using `<table>` elements for anything that is not tabular data. You'll find it hard to handle responsiveness using that markup.

A modern solution for your layout is flexbox:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #212121;
  padding: 30px;
}
.flex-images {
  display: flex;
}
.flex-images div {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.flex-images img {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block;
}
@media (max-width: 539px) {
  .flex-images {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-images">
  <div>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/300" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/600/400" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flex-images">
  <div>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/500/250" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/300" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flex-images">
  <div>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/150/350" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/750/300" />
  </div>
</div>
```

If you don't want the images to be cropped, give all images in same row the same height.

Comment: I had already tried setting the border to none prior to posting.  It did nothing to solve the issue.  My understanding is that border:none;  has no effect when the borders are collapsed or am I mistaken?  The images are meant to cropped and are just temporary placeholder images to be replaced afterwards.  I will try your <div> and flex solution when I get some more time.

Comment: @Ismail, your understanding is [incorrect](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/nqoges5y/). Well, I guess I should be flattered you'll waste some of your precious time implementing the easy fix I provided by snapping my fingers. Thank you, I won't be taking anymore of your time. Godspeed!

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It turned out the problem wasn't border related at all.  For some reason, the div's were not filling the entire cell in the table, leaving gaps and giving the appearance of having borders.  As advised, I have now switched the layout from table to div.  Once again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing out your CSS for this...

```css
.test {
  /* margin: auto; remove */
  width: 1000px;
  height: 583px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  /*Add to remove border and place them on eachother*/
  border: none;
  margin: -1px;
}

.test2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*Same thing down here*/
  border: none;
  margin: -1px;
}
```

Please describe the problem with more detail as well.

Comment: It never occurred to me to try a negative margin - I will try this when I get some spare time. Setting border to none does not work, as I had already tried this prior to posting.

Comment: Thanks Philip, but unfortunately setting the border to none and using a negative margin didn't work for me.  Could there be any other reason why the borders are still there?

Comment: @Ismail , I believe Andrei's answer is correct. Using tables is a bad way to format this, use div's instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It turned out the problem wasn't border related at all.  For some reason, the div's were not filling the entire cell in the table, leaving gaps and giving the appearance of having borders.  As advised, I have now switched the layout from table to div.  Once again, thanks.